# How to define a POJO to hold list of data from submit form?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to insert list of items into a database table submitted from multiple select form.

My submit form is:

```
<form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/">
    <div>
        <label>User:</label> 
        <select name="customer">
            <option value="">Select Customer</option>
            <c:forEach var="c" items="${ cList }">
                <option value="${ c.id }">${ c.name }</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </div><br>
    <div>
        <label>Hobby:</label> 
        <select name="product" multiple size="8">
            <!-- <option value="">Select Items</option> -->
            <c:forEach var="p" items="${ pList }">
                <option value = "${ p.id }">${ p.productName }</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

And so far i have done this:

My Transaction POJO:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transcation")
public class Transcation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    private Long id;
    @JoinColumn
    @OneToOne
    private Customer customer;
    @JoinColumn
    @OneToMany
    private List<Product> product;
    ...
```

My Product POJO:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String productName;
    ...
```

But when i run this project i get this type of database table for transcation and product:

[Product table in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24a7V.jpg)

[Transaction table in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDJML.jpg)

I need to insert the customers' transaction with the list of items and customer id in the transaction table.

Comment: Do you actually having problem in mapping the entity `List<Product>` in `Transaction` ?

Comment: @ShafinMahmud, yes and i also want to know how to insert the list of products into transaction table.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the database tables are generated from the Entity you defined. Hence its okay to have such tables generated. But the thing is you are interpreting a wrong relationship between `Tranasaction` and `Product`.

Think - Is it really an `OneToMany` relation ? I guess No. Cause not only an `Transaction` contains list of `Product` but also a `Product` could be in multiple `Tracnsaction`. So this should be an unidirectional `ManyToMany` relation.

If I understand your business this okay then just annotate you `Transaction` Entity like below (having `@JoinTable` for the `ManyToMany` relation.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transcation")
public class Transcation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id")
    private Customer customer;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "transaction_product",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "transaction_id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"))
    private List<Product> productList;
    ...
```

Having `@JoinTable` actually creates separate mapping table `tranasction_product` in the database having foreign key reference with `transaction` and `product` table primary key.

**Saving this Relation from UI**

Assuming you have the selected `Customer` and the selected List of `Product` from the submission. Now just create a `Transaction`. Simply assign the values and save your `Tranasction` object through an opened `session`

```
Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
transaction.setCustomer(customer);
transaction.setProductList(productList);
```

Comment: Based on your description i have the following issue: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835354/how-to-insert-the-multiple-value-from-select-form-into-database)

Comment: If you find this answer resolves your asking issue then you should accept it. And sure, your another question could be addressed there. But if it solves your part of the problem accept it first.

Answer (score 1):

Your Entities seems to be correct.
First please add products into database. Consider you have added products already. id of these are 1,2,3.

Before persisting transaction load products by ids and add into product list.

Then create object of transaction :

```
Transaction = new Transaction();
transaction.setProducts(products); //list of products loaded already into list
```

Then set other parameters and finally just save this transaction.

Comment: I guess the Entity relations are not correct here. And @Space having the problem of produced schema with unexpected relations.

Comment: Please try this. This will work..

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "products")
private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

Answer (score 0):

You want to map an collection type (List) in Transaction table. You should try to annotate the list with @ElementCollection annotation like below:

```
...
@JoinColumn
@OneToMany
@ElementCollection
private List<Product> product;
```

Of course we take for granted that `Product` table actually exists.

Comment: but i am getting the database schema incorrect...as mentioned in database table above...transaction table does not possess product_id reference key...