# How to insert the multiple value from select form into database?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My submission form:

```
<form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/">
    <div>
        <label>User:</label> 
        <select name="customer">
            <option value="">Select Customer</option>
            <c:forEach var="c" items="${ cList }">
                <option value="${ c.id }">${ c.name }</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </div><br>
    <div>
        <label>Hobby:</label> 
        <select name="product" multiple size="8">
            <!-- <option value="">Select Items</option> -->
            <c:forEach var="p" items="${ pList }">
                <option value = "${ p.id }">${ p.productName }</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postHome(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute Transcation t){
    transactionDao.addTransaction(t);
    return "home";
}
```

In TransactionDaoImpl:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void addTranscation(Transcation t) {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.save(t);
    session.close();
}
```

Based on your idea, what type of modifications do i have to make to perform insert operation.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about the requirement?

Comment: Are you able to get the values from form to Controller?

Comment: do you able to bind the `Transaction` model from the form submission in the handler ? I guess No.